# How in WinSCP .NET assembly read remote file to memory

Tags: .net, winscp, winscp-net

I have to read a file content or read the file bytes and need to store in it our database.

Using .NET `System.IO.File` we can simply call `File.ReadAllBytes(file)`.

How to do it in WinSCP .NET assembly, using `RemoteFileInfo`?

Answer (score 3):

The WinSCP .NET assembly supports providing the contents of a remote file using streams using the [`Session.GetFile` method](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_getfile):

```
using (Stream stream = session.GetFile("/path/file.ext"))
{
    // use the stream
}
```